# Why does this regular expression matches the string?

Tags: java, regex

```
String p = "(a|ab|c)*";

String s = "aabcab";

Boolean b = s.matches(p);

System.out.println(b);
```

This pattern 'p' matches:

```
1) 0 or more single 'a': a, aa, aaa
2) 0 or more single 'ab': ab, abab, ababab
3) 0 or more single 'c': c, cc, ccc
```

Why does it match 'aabcab'? In the 3 patterns above, there isn't any string consisting of a mixture of characters 'a', 'b', and 'c'

Comment: The star matches any number of the preceding group, in this case 'a' - 'ab' - 'c' - 'ab'.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, the order of the group doesn't matter? i.e. 'ccab'

Comment: It does not when the pattern is a or ab or c any number of times. You did not specify a pattern with an order. Also, you could have *tried* `System.out.println("ccab".matches("(a|ab|c)*"));` (but since you ask, it's `true`).

Comment: What is the actual logic behind what you are trying to match?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I am reading and just trying to understand how it matches, given the string and pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kleene star operation doesn't distribute over the alternative: the rule you were most likely looking for is: `(a*)|(ab)*|(c*)`.

Your pattern `p` will match any sequence of characters formed be zero or more repetitions of ANY of the three given alternatives over and over again, instead of repetitions of each type that may not mix.

Comment: can you draw a finite state machine diagram for this regular expression?